# python - merge function output comes out sorted

Tags: python, sorting, merge

below are my codes

```
vals = [1,123,223,510,2356,7810]
id = ['AAA', 'AA', 'A', 'BBB', 'BB', 'B']
dd = pd.DataFrame(vals,index=id,columns=['Values'])
ddd = ["AAA","A", "AA", "A", "A", "BBB", "BBB", "A"]
ddd = pd.DataFrame(ddd,columns=['Values']).set_index('Values')
dout = pd.merge(ddd,dd,left_index=True,right_index=True,sort=False)
```

my output is sorted

```
     Values
A       223
A       223
A       223
A       223
AA      123
AAA       1
BBB     510
BBB     510
```

whereas the sequence for dataframe ddd is ['AAA', 'AA', 'A', 'BBB', 'BB', 'B'], which is the output sequence I want i.e unsorted. I have added sort=False but that doesnt work. what am I missing?

Comment: `ddd = pd.DataFrame(ddd,columns=['Values']).set_index('Values')`  This line is suspicious

Comment: it was to create an empty df with index = [AAA, A, AA, A, A, BBB, BBB, A]. All I want is corresponding values for for those ids from dataframe dd. And the output shouldnt be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

the only way around the issue was adding these two lines at the bottom of my code and it gave me what I wanted

```
dout_new = dout.drop_duplicates().T
columns_ = ddd.reset_index().Values.to_list()
dout_new = dout_new[columns_].T
```

if anyone has a sleeker answer, let us know!